# Converting raster data to have the attached results using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, kml, arcgis-10.4, classification

I have a huge 30x30m reclassified raster dataset (10 classes) (in the size of Portugal) and I would like to find the easiest way to convert it to kml, having a similar result to the map we bought attached below.

If you look in the map, you will see that they poligonize each cell of the raster into 9 different shapefiles (the 9 small folders in the left side) according to a range of value, like "WSP < 3.4", "3.5 < WSP < 4.1" and etc.

Also they could keep a streched colour to each cell.

Normally when I transform a raster to a polygon it becomes one shapefile and if I want to transform it to a kml that have different folders I have to extract by attribute each value of my shapefile and convert each one of this shapes to kml. After I need to go in each one on Google Earth and set a color manually, paying attention if it is in the colour scale or not.

How can I make it easily and right to have a result like this one?

I have a ArcGIS 10.4 with spatial analyst license.

Desired Results
[image]

Comment: Did you try to use `Map to KML` tool from ArcGIS toolbox for each piece of map you have?

Comment: Yes, I tried this tool. But as I said below I need something else to produce this result that I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using the [KML Conversion tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/kml-conversion.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_8EF31101E88C49F8A57C12A88428C279) in ArcGIS will allow you to conver your Raster to KML.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers!

Yes I know and I use these tools, in my opinion the map to kml is the one that most attend what I want but I still have to do a lot of manual work before using  the tool. I'm talking about a raster in the size of country  resolution of 30 meters with 10 or more classifications, in my application sometimes it is not interesting to see a raster like this on Google Earth, because I want to click and select the layers I want on or off.

Also when converting a huge raster to kml it loses a lot of quality and information, because the ideal pixel size for a kml file is 2048x2048 or less.

So, I have to transform my raster into a polygon, when you use the raster to polygon tool, your raster become a single shapefile with all the attributes together, if you convert this shapefile  directly to kml you will not have the possibility to turn off or on your layers, all the values will be together. So  before use the tool "map to kml" I have to break the feature in 10 other different features, transform to kml, rename and put a color in each one of them.

This is a hard work, specially when your bosses wants to change the results all the time, our when you have to split a country in 4 because it has over 1 millions of polygon. If I split a country in 4, and my raster had cells with 10 different values. It means that when I convert to shapefile I'll have to create 40 other shapes, group than by zones, put a color manually in the 40 shapes and them convert  it to kml.

=/